# How to add a "Please Select.." option in Html.EnumDropDownListFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

**Model**;

```
public Location? Format { get; set; }
```

**Enum;**

```
public enum Location
{
    Online = 1,
    School= 2
}
```

**Razor;**

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Format, "Select a Format", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Format).
```

**Question;**

How can i add a "Please Select.." option in the `EnumDropDownListFor()` which only shows up as a 'label' and not as a dropdown option?

**note;**

I'm getting the data from a table in my database, so I'd prefer not to have an actual row in there with "Please select".

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Format, "Select a Format")` will generate a `<label>` element associated with the `<select>` element (although it would be odd to have your property nullable if you do not want the `null` option)

Comment: You can add an `object` in list when you get data from Database.